# RVM Not Finding Library

Tags: centos, centos5, ruby, rvm

I am running CentOS 5.9 and installed RVM on it. However, whenever I run `rvm requirements` or `rvm install 1.9.3`, I get:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1()(64bit) for package: libyaml-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
libyaml-devel-0.1.2-3.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package libyaml-devel-0.1.2-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package libyaml-devel-0.1.2-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
```

However, When I try to install libyaml-0.so.1(), it attempts to install libyaml-devel which is already installed. What exactly is libyaml-0.so.1 and how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`libyaml` is library used by `ruby` `Psych` which is used by `rubygems` to load gem specifications.

make sure your rvm is up to date:

```
rvm get stable
```

and then try requirements again:

```
rvm requirements
```

if this does not help open a ticket for rvm: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues